# Check if values in a column exist elsewhere in a dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,3,4,5],'c':[3,4,5,6],'d':[5,3,2,4]})
```

I want to check if elements in column `d` exist elsewhere in its corresponding row. So the outcome I want is

```
[False, True, False, True]
```

Towards that end, I used

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['d'] in x[['a','b','c']], axis=1)
```

but this is somehow giving me `[False, False, False, False]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
out = (df[['a','b','c']].T==df['d']).any()
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of numpy broadcasting, you can do it easily:

```
(df[['d']].to_numpy() == df.to_numpy())[:, :-1].any(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

Using numpy is about as fast as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Use [eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to broadcast equality comparison across the columns. Then check if there are [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) matches in the row:

```py
df.drop(columns='d').eq(df['d'], axis=0).any(axis=1).array
<PandasArray>
[False, True, False, True]
Length: 4, dtype: bool
```

Speedwise, a numpy option is best.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df.eq(df.pop('d'),axis=0).any(1)#.values
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add 'values':

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['d'] in x[['a','b','c']].values, axis=1)
Out[11]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

What you've typed is checking whether x['d'] is in the set of **keys** of x[['a','b','c']] not values. Dictionaries work in similar ways:

```
1 in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
Out[30]: False
1 in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.values()
Out[31]: True
```